# does stored procedure enhance the performance in an acess databank,why?

Tags: performance, ms-access, stored-procedures

Which one enhace the performance in an Access:

- Having stored procedures
- writing our query in VB code
- or writing our query in Datasource of our control property

  logicaly the first one should enhance the performance but here I have read another thing.What do you mean?

could you please explain me technicaly or show me a reference?

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about an MDB file, then you must be using "stored procedure" to refer to saved queries.  Saved queries can execute more quickly than in-line SQL, because the query plan is stored with the query; when you execute inline SQL, the SQL has to be compiled into a query plan.

If you write a query into the `DataSource` property of a control, Access creates a hidden saved query, so the performance should be similar.

More generally, are you asking this question because you or your users have observed poor performance?  If so, where is the performance poor?  That information might help us suggest a good opportunity for improving the performance.

For example, suppose your form is an order form, and you have text boxes showing the customer's name and address.  The record source of the form is the `[Orders]` table.  The name text box has as its control source

```
SELECT [CustomerName] FROM [Customers] WHERE [CustomerID] = [CustomerIdTextBox]
```

Similarly, the control source of the address text box:

```
SELECT [Address] FROM [Customers] WHERE [CustomerID] = [CustomerIdTextBox]
```

In this case, you'll improve your performance markedly by changing the record source:

```
SELECT [Orders].*, [Customers].[CustomerName], [Customers].[Address]
FROM [Orders] INNER JOIN [Customers] ON [Orders].[CustomerID] = [Customers].[ID]
```

Then change the control source for the name text box to `[CustomerName]` and for the address text box to `[Address]`.

Why is this faster?  In the first design, you had two queries (or, rather, a query for each item you're pulling from the `[Customers]` table).  In the new design, you have only one query.

If, on the other hand, you are asking about performance because of a theoretical idea that one approach might be faster than another, then you should use the approach that is simplest to maintain.  If you can't observe the difference in performance, there's no benefit to using a more performant solution.

Answer (score 1):

A stored procedure still needs to be executed. In Access, it has to be executed on your own computer, with a regular DBMS it still needs to be executed on the server. Which approach is more efficient depends on the problem you are solving.

Comment: thank you for your answer,let me explain my scnario a little bit more detailed:

I have a form that contains 10 control and these controls is filled with their queries(they are only simple select queries)  when the form loads.

Comment: Doesn't sound like anything *near* what would require a stored procedure for anything. Is there some problem you need so solve?

Comment: Your form loads too slowly? Keep your queries in your controls and optimize your sql.

Comment: at beginning loaded in 20 sec I indexed some fields and now loads in 5 seconds.I thought that may be stored procedure help me.My queries are in my controls. the queries are simple SELECT.in my situation SP does not help me?

Comment: Try it if you don't believe me. A stored procedure would save you the trouble of transmitting a long query, or might be appropriate if you have separate applications that need to do the same complex thing. There's no point in your case. And you already have evidence that your queries are slow.

Comment: It is not clear what kind of store procedure the poser is talking about. If you talking about a SQL server store procedure, then as such this does NOT run on the client side, but runs server side. However, if you talking about the new store procedures available in Access 2010, then yes, they do run client side when run on a network, but when published to SharePoint or office 365 then the store procedures run server side.

Comment: I was talking about Access used stand-alone with an .mdb file-- there's only one computer involved, so everything runs on it.