# Query Performance: Using saved queries vs adding constraints during runtime to a query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have multiple forms with specific buttons to show/hide data (f.e. data from last year/all data). I've been thinking a while about query performances and I can't really find a good source which explains how access handles those.

In particular I was wondering, if there is a performance difference between using a saved query (for a specific case, like 'data from last year') and appending parameters to a  query during runtime (say add 'where xy = -1' to a query with no constraints). Will both querys be executed in the backend, or will any constraints I add to an existing query via VBA be executed in the frontend?

Should I create a query for every possible scenario or use only one query where I add parameters during runtime?

Fyi I'm using jet and my database is split to frontend and backend (Access 2007). The backend will be located on a network folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Access is a file based system rather than a dedicated server, absolutely nothing is run in the back-end, even if it is stored there, everything is executed locally in whichever copy you have open, namely the front-end or the back-end.

Comment: So just to clarify: if I have a query, every data from every requested field gets transferred from the backend to the frontend and there the data gets evaluated?

Comment: @Christian I'm not sure exactly which words best describe it, but essentially yes, all evaluation is carried out by the local copy which you have open (should almost always be the front-end)

Comment: Ty, I didn't know that. I guess I misinterpreted another statement I was given a while ago.

Answer (score 2):

Check the answers to this question: [does stored procedure enhance the performance in an acess databank,why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566790/does-stored-procedure-enhance-the-performance-in-an-acess-databank-why)

Mostly covers what you are asking for.

Comment: Ty for your reply. The link you've posted imo doesn't cover what I was asking for.  I can't see any answer to the question in which case a query is executed in the backend.